# How to rebase an old commit on a deleted branch?

Tags: git

I have a quite strange git request. Here's a portion of my git history:

```
           -----2----- master
               / \
              /   3--- new dev
           --1  old dev
```

- 1 come from a deleted dev branch
- 2 is a merge of the deleted dev branch with master
- 3 is a new dev branch derived from master

I would like to connect 3 to 1 like this:

```
    -----2----- master 
        / 
    ---1---3--- dev
```

The old dev and the new branch are now the same branch dev.
Is there a way to achieve this ?
Thanks to those who will answer.

**Edit:**
The rest of my repo looks like this:

```
-2------5----7--- master 
  \    /    /
   3--4----6----- dev
```

So when I do as chepner said, I end up with this:

```
 -----2------5----7--------- master
       \    /    /
 ---1---3--4----6----------- dev
            \
             3'-------4'--5'--6' newdev
```

I want the newdev branch to have the same history of my dev branch with history changes made by the command of chepner.
I hope it's clear enough this time.

Comment: Branch heads are just special names for commits. The hash of the commit can be used just as easily as a branch name for rebasing.

Comment: Btw, what for? old_dev and new_dev already share history. old_dev is 1 and new_dev is 1-2-3 (and master is 1-2)

Comment: You're right, it has absolutely no incidence on my project. It's just to have a prettier history graph and to train myself at the edition of a git history.

Comment: I have to say I find the ascii graphs to be _very_ confusing. History goes from left to right, but yet your branch names are on the left side of the drawing, while they should in fact be right of 7, 6, and 6'

Comment: I'm definitely not a designer... Is it better now ?

Comment: re your updated graphs: old_dev is already contained in new_dev's history, so it already is "the same branch": 1(old_dev)-2-3-4-6(new_dev). Also, 3 and 4 wouldn't be duplicated after rebasing, they are already contained in the history; and 5 was never on branch (new_)dev. So rebasing would have only copied/moved the commit 6

Comment: I started writing an answer, but the more I tried, the less I could figure out what you're trying to achieve. There doesn't seem to be any one diagram in your question that shows either the current or desired state, they all show part of the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Branches in Git are simply "labels" and the active label moves with each new commit on this branch. That the old_dev branch was deleted is irrelevant here, the commit was merged and is thus part of the master branch's history.

The solution to your request is quite trivial:

```
git rebase --onto 1 2 new_dev
```

It will take all commits from 2..new_dev (excludes 2, includes 3) and place them onto commit 1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked as you said. But I realized I haven't been clear enough. I continued merging my dev branch on master after the portion of history I showed you. So when I do as you said, I end up with two new-dev branches. I'll edit my post to be clearer.